# HTML styling- text needs to be on fewer lines

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML with a really long label. The issue is that the label looks like this:

```
this is a message
that is very very 
very long.. and is 
spanning multiple 
lines..:
```

I want it to look like this:

```
 this is a message that is very very very 
 long.. and is spanning multiple lines..:
```

Here is my code

```
<ul>
    <li class="left">
        <LABEL for="field_1">this is a message that is very very very long.. and is spanning multiple lines..:</LABEL>                              
    </li>
    <li>
        <input  id="field_1"  name="field_1" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 
    </li>                       

</ul>
```

Comment: Post your CSS too please. Also, a jsFiddle.net example is useful.

Comment: all you need to do is change the width of your li

Comment: We need more info and context. Something is defining the max-width of the li, and we can't know what. Could we either have an example or more of the html and the CSS?

Comment: And, to be honest that's a pretty poor way of structuring a form. If you must at least put the label and input inside a div which inside the `li`. ...but I still wouldn't do it that way. Try reviewing the snippet here: http://html5doctor.com/element-index/#form2

Answer (score 3):

Use this CSS:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="left">
        <input  id="field_1"  name="field_1" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 
        <LABEL for="field_1">this is a message that is very very very long.. and is spanning multiple lines..:</LABEL>                              
    </li>                       
</ul>
```

You can adjust `max-width` property as your need.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vbdmP/

Comment: inline-block and max-width don't work well on some IE browsers.

Comment: both are supported in IE8+, I see no reason to cater to browsers older than this.  upvote.

Comment: what if the width is being applied to parent element like `li` or `ul`?

Comment: @Mr_Green I think the point here is `display: inline-block;` which make the text wrapped, if the label is wrapped by `li` then the text will be wrapped as the `li`'s width. Am I right? @Vladimir Kocjancic: thanks, I didn't notice that, but I think this code is still accepted as hdrenollet said.

Comment: @Mr_Green I have read the question again and updated my answer, use `width` is the choice, thanks :)

Comment: but now the check box is messed up, it's going into that, there's no division

Comment: @nivyaj what does this mean? `it's going into that`.. post your css code.

Comment: @nivyaj I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/vbdmP/. I have updated my answer by the way.